# *EXCEL* If a range of cells contain *STRING* then extract the sum of decimal numbers from positive cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, data-manipulation

I've spent a long time trying to figure this out now and have had no progress so far. So what it is i am trying to do is gather the sum of all decimal numbers found in a range of strings in a tables column, this can be done on an individual basis using the below formula:

`=LOOKUP(9.9E+307,--LEFT(MID(A2,MIN(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}, $A2&"1023456789")),999),ROW(INDIRECT("1:999"))))`

The reason i do not wish to add a dedicated column to the table is because this is being used in only very specific use cases on a financial tracker where an order has been made with multiple items and a single item has later been refunded, the table will then be updated as shown:

*PRE REFUND:* `Amazon Marketplace   //   £110`

*POST REFUND:* `Amazon Marketplace [R-50.20]   //   £110`

So using the above formula i would be able to pull 50.20 from the string. Now, what i need to have done is something similar to the below, this does not work but i'm unsure as to what formula may help with this:

`SUM(SUMIF(AprilActivity[ITEM],"*[R-*",LOOKUP(9.9E+307,--LEFT(MID(AprilActivity[ITEM],MIN(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}, $AprilActivity[ITEM]&"1023456789")),999),ROW(INDIRECT("1:999"))))))`

Comment: Can you give us some insight how your data looks like (e.g. a screenshot of your spreadsheet?

Comment: ^  Including an expected output!

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delayed response, i needed to obsfucate some data before posting, i have arranged a description of my document alongside some screenshots on imgur, please let me know if anything else could be of use. https://imgur.com/a/v7OzWJt

Answer (score 1):

You have only provided a single example, in which it appears that the number you wish to return is that between two substrings:

- `[R-`
- `]`

If that is what you really want, then:

```
=SUM(--MID(myRange,FIND("[R-",myRange)+3, FIND("]",myRange)-FIND("[R-",myRange)-3))
```

will add all the numbers in `myRange` that meet those specifications.

And you can replace `myRange` with `AprilActivity[ITEM]`, for example.

Comment: Thanks for this, i know my question was badly worded so i appriciate your effort trying to understand my issue. Although this would work perfectly in the case that every cell in the range contained a refund (**[R-....]**) it will end up throwing an error if a cell does not contain the refund identifier, to get by this **IFERROR** can be used, as seen here: 

`=SUM(IFERROR(--MID(myRange,FIND("[R-",myRange)+3, FIND("]",myRange)-FIND("[R-",myRange)-3),0))`

Comment: I'm glad you can adapt what I have provided to your real problem.  In the future, be aware that if the data you provide does not adequately encompass the true nature of your data, proffered solutions are unlikely be optimum.